# Shift all tags in file to the right

Tags: org-mode, indentation

In a `.org` file, I can align all my tags to the right with `C-u C-c C-q`.

I'd like more space before text runs into tags in a file.

Is there a variable for the location of the tags column in the org document?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340741/how-can-i-control-in-org-mode-the-distance-of-tags-from-the-text-they-apply-to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `org-tags-column`.

Citation of the Documentation:

> The column to which tags should be indented in a headline.
>   If this number is positive, it specifies the column.  If it is negative,
>   it means that the tags should be flushright to that column.  For example,
>   -80 works well for a normal 80 character screen.
>   When 0, place tags directly after headline text, with only one space in
>   between.

You can set it as file local variable by appending the following comment lines to your org file:

```
# Local Variables:
# org-tags-column: 100
# End:
```

Comment: I set `org-tags-column` globally using `M-x describe-variable  RET org-tags-column` and choosing the customize option. Changes were not reflected until I used `C-u C-c C-q` again to realign the tags.